# Invalid Encryption Keys Password when enabling shared Configuration to Azure file share in iis

Tags: iis, azure, share, web-farm

I want to set up to Azure VM web servers as a farm with shared configuration and content being stored in an Azuure File share.

I have been following this tutorial : http://officeline.gr/2017/05/17/azure-web-farm-using-iis-azure-file-storage/

The Web Server VM's are Standard DS2 (2 vcpus, 7 GB memory) running Windows Server 2016 datacenter. IIS version 10.0.14393.0

I was able to successfully export the configuration from one IIS to file storage. I can see the 3 files it creates in file storage through the azure portal. The issues I have is when I try and set up iis to use the shared configuration in file storage. I keep getting a Invalid password when I enter the Encryption Keys Password. 
[image]

I swear I entered the same encryption password that I used to export the configuration. Am I supposed to just make up an encryption password or should it be set to something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test in my lab, I meet the same error with you. **I think maybe the blog miss mount file share on VM.** When I do this, I get the same result with the blog.

[image]

Note:Encryption Keys Password is not your file share password. This password is set when you use IIS Manager to export configuration files.